How to boot GNOME on Debian and not GNU GRUB
I bought a Beelink Mini S (Mini PC) and I have never used Linux before, so I created a bootable USB with Debian 12 using Rufus and following a guide (windows partition was still there by the way), the GNOME was booted fine and made the changes that I need, which was very simple and in the next day when I turned on the mini pc it was all black screen.
Following the guide again, I manually deleted all partitions and created one from scratch (without windows partition anymore). So I have a SWAP partition, a EXT 4 in / and another one that was created automatically by the system. I chose then the GNOME package so that I could have a GUI/UI for me, which is easier.
But I cannot escape this screen and then black screen again:

I read something that is because of cannot finding the boot, which is different from Windows. But I don't know what else I need to change. This is my BIOS currently:




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
